# Google Analytics API filter returning too strict of values

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I'm attempting to filter data down by page path which is simple enough in most cases. However, I'm getting an unexpected result returned:

```
data = service.data().ga().get(
        ids='ga:' + profile_id,
        start_date='2018-06-15',
        end_date='yesterday',
        metrics='ga:sessions,ga:newUsers,ga:sessionDuration,ga:goal12Completions,ga:goal4Completions,ga:goal5Completions,ga:bounces,ga:users',
        dimensions='ga:date,ga:sourceMedium,ga:userType,ga:country,ga:region,ga:city,ga:pagePath',
        sort='ga:date',
        filters='ga:pagePath=~/path1/path2.*',
        start_index=index,
        max_results=10000).execute()

    return data
```

**The data within Analytics has page data structured thus:**

- domain.com/path1/path2/
- domain.com/path1/path2/some
- domain.com/path1/path2/extra
- domain.com/path1/path2/parameters

I expect the filter above to return data for each of these page structures, however, it only returns data for pages that have a parameter after path 2:

- domain.com/path1/path2/some
- domain.com/path1/path2/extra
- domain.com/path1/path2/parameters

**I've tried various ways to filter this data including:**

```
filters='ga:pagePath=@/path1/path2'

filters='ga:pagePath=@/path2'
```

I've also attempted to pass in the search string as a variable into the filter which produced the same result.

I've also tested it out in the query explorer which gives the same results as my script. However, filtering for the same regex expression in the advanced filter area of GA gives me the results I expect from the first bullet list above. I also threw some of the data into a text file and did a regex search on it which gave me all of the expected results.

My next step is testing taking away specific metrics to see if there's a combination creating a problem but there shouldn't be according to the documentation.

Any suggestions on next steps for debugging or a correction of the filter?

Comment: You're regular expression looks correct.  Are you sure you have values for pagePath that are /path1/path2 alone?  What happens when you change the filter to filters='ga:pagePath=~/path1.*' ?

Comment: I've done a bunch of digging since and the core problem is mixing pagePath as a dimension with any other dimension besides date. The dimension and metric explorer indicates that it should be possible but that's the source of the issue. The issue with doing only path1 is that it's path2 I actually care about. That said, I have tried only path2 to no avail. I'm convinced there's either an undocumented mixture that isn't allowed or there's a bug in the API somewhere. It returns matched data, but only includes URLs with stuff after path2.

Comment: As you may know, if one of the dimensions is undefined, no row will be returned.  Is is it possible that you are including dimensions that are undefined for some of the rows, eliminating path2?

Comment: I went ahead and tested it with just the dimensions `pagePath` and `sourceMedium` to the same result. Every record in GA records at least that so there should be no null value present there. I've also tried every combination from the original post alone with `pagePath` to the same outcome (path+city, path+region, etc.). The only dimension that has values returning undefined/null results is `region` in some instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusting the filtering to a "contains substring" method will solve your problem. Refer to the Google Analytics API [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) to see all of the available filtering options. Also, I would highly recommend double-checking your original data source within the Google Analytics user interface to ensure the URLs that you're seeking are in fact available.

```
 filters='ga:pagePath=@<YOUR-SUBSTRING>',
```